# Write a macro to define a new command and locally invoke it

Tags: macros

I would write a macro `\defineThisCommand` that defines a new command `\TheCommand` and, then, locally invokes it. The code has to be something like this:

```
\defineThisCommand{}{
      \newcommand \ThisCommand{
           #1
      }
      \ThisCommand
}

\begin{document}
    \defineTopicOne{Some text printed}
    \defineTopicTwo{and this too}
\end{document}
```

generating, at the end, the output

```
Some text printed

and this too
```

Please, can you suggest me a way of solving this problem?

Comment: Note that you have to place `%` at the end of lines if you don't want those line endings to turn into a space (this isn't necessary after macros like `\ThisCommand`, as spaces are ignored there, but after the opening braces and the closing brace of the `\newcommand`, as well as after `#1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\defineanduse[2]
  {%
    \newcommand#1{#2}%
    #1%
  }

\begin{document}

\defineanduse\mycmd{abc}

\defineanduse\myothercmd{def}

\mycmd\myothercmd

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When TeX finds a control sequence `\foo`, there are two cases to distinguish first: either TeX is doing macro expansion, or it isn’t. The latter case is not of a concern in your situation, so we look at what happens in the former case. The cases are:

1. the control sequence has been assigned a meaning, or
2. the control sequence is undefined.

In the first case, TeX uses the meaning, which should be appropriate to the context: if `\foo` is a macro, it will be expanded, if it is a `\chardef` token the corresponding character will be printed, and so on.

In the second case, TeX will stop, issue an error message and *ignore* the undefined token.

Thus you can’t do like you’d like to, unless you have previously defined a bunch of macros

```
\newcommand\defineThisCommand[1]{\newcommand\ThisCommand{#1}\ThisCommand}
```

for every local command you need. This obviously defies your intention: you cannot have `\defineOtherCommand` if you haven’t previously defined it.

The strategy to use is to have a generic macro with *two* arguments:

```
\newcommand\define[2]{%
  \newcommand#1{#2}% define the local command
  #2% and also use it now
}
```

which allows you to say

```
\define\ThisCommand{whatever}
```

to do what you want.